# Wordpress: Force HTTPS using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https

**Problem**
Using .htaccess to force HTTPs on my Wordpress site does not work

**Tried solution**
On my Wordpress site I have the following .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But to force using HTTPs I'am trying to replace it with this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain\.dk [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.dk/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Result**
The website is no longer working (here is the website response):

```
This page isn’t working
www.mydomain.dk redirected you too many times.

Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

**Questions**

1. Why can't I force using HTTPs on my Wordpress website?
2. What can I do to make it work?

Best regards, Henning

Comment: "I'am trying to **replace** it with this code" - Why "replace" it? The first block of code is necessary to rewrite the request to the WordPress front-controller (if you are using "pretty" permalinks).

Comment: How is your SSL connection managed? Is the SSL cert installed directly on the application server or are you using some kind of front-end proxy, CDN (eg. Cloudflare) or load balancer to manage the SSL?

Comment: @MrWhite sorry, but I don't know the answer for any of your questions. I'm not a developer myself.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying the surggested solutions - I tried to change the URL in the Wordpress settings to HTTPS and now it works.

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, I was just about to try the Really Simple SSL plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's quite likely then that the redirect-loop was simply caused by WordPress itself redirecting back to HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

If your web server is running Apache, you can redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS by returning to the default .htaccess configuration and than adding the following code to your .htaccess file.
This is also the recommended method for redirecting WordPress to Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, probably the easiest way to implement HTTPS on your WordPress site would be to install the following plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

Comment: Although if the code in the question (that checks `SERVER_PORT`) is resulting in a redirect loop then checking `HTTPS` will also (very likely) result in the same redirect loop. In this case it is quite likely that the site is behind a front-end proxy, CDN (eg. Cloudflare) or load balancer that is managing the SSL connection.